# C#: FastColoredTextBox not updating syntax highlighting

Tags: c#

i´m new with C# and i´m required to color a text depending on what it is, for example my keywords have to be blue, numbers red, Parentheses brown, brackets sky blue, well you get the idea.

I have my FastColoredTextBox as ftbT and my method ftbT_TextChanged:

```
private void ftbT_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Regex keywords = new Regex(@"\b((P|p)rincipal|(I|i)ntevalo|(N|n)ivel|(D|d)imensiones|(I|i)nicio_(P|p)ersonaje|(U|u)bicacion_(S|s)alida|(P|p)ared|(E|e)nemigo|(C|c)aminata|(C|c)asilla|(V|v)arias_(C|c)asillas|(P|p)ersonaje|(P|p)aso|(V|v)ariable|(R|r)ango_(C|c)asillas)\b");

    Range range = (sender as FastColoredTextBox).Range;
    e.ChangedRange.ClearStyle();
    e.ChangedRange.SetStyle(BlueStyle, keywords.ToString(), RegexOptions.Multiline);
}
```

But when i run the application it will not change any writen word to the style selected also my style is defined like this:

```
Style BlueStyle = new TextStyle(Brushes.Blue, null, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic);
```

Where "Brushes.Blue" is taken from `using FastColoredTextBoxNS;`

I tried to change the code inside the method to:

```
private void ftbT_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Regex keywords = new Regex(@"\b((P|p)rincipal|(I|i)ntevalo|(N|n)ivel|(D|d)imensiones|(I|i)nicio_(P|p)ersonaje|(U|u)bicacion_(S|s)alida|(P|p)ared|(E|e)nemigo|(C|c)aminata|(C|c)asilla|(V|v)arias_(C|c)asillas|(P|p)ersonaje|(P|p)aso|(V|v)ariable|(R|r)ango_(C|c)asillas)\b");

    Range range = (sender as FastColoredTextBox).Range;
    range.ClearStyle(BlueStyle);
    range.SetStyle(BlueStyle, keywords.ToString());
}
```

But is also not changing the keywords to blue nor italic.

Any idea what i am missing or doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

So, for some reason FastColoredTextBox the latest version didn't worked, after checking with a friend who had version 2.7.2.0 I created a new proyect and added v2.7.2.0 instead of the latest one and It Worked !